# Infinite dimensional symplectic geometry

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, quantum-mechanics, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Could anyone comment on possible references concerning infinite dimensionsal symplectic manifolds?. I am mainly concerned with hilbert spaces, so i am not interested in the convenient analysis approach to the topic given, for instance, by Michor and collaborators,

More spectifically, I am interested in an infinite-dimensional analogue of the Marsden-Weinstein reduction and applications. I am specially concerned with its possible uses in quantum mechanics.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Marsden and Weinstein's [original paper](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/bib/1974/01-MaWe1974/) already contains infinite-dimensional examples (pp. 125-126, and lemma p. 123).

Comment: Haller, Stefan; Vizman, Cornelia Non-linear Grassmannians as coadjoint orbits. Math. Ann. 329 (2004), no. 4, 771–785. [arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305089)

Answer (score 14):

Aspects of symplectic topology hold in the infinite dimensional setting. A notable difference is that there are different notions for what a symplectic form should be: there is the notion of a strong symplectic form where $\omega$ is required to induce an isomorphism $\mathbb H\rightarrow \mathbb H^*$, or a weak one, where this map is only injective. In finite dimensions this cannot occur as an injective map from a finite dimensional space to a space with the same dimension is necessarily bijective.

For strong symplectic forms some things are known. The following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3200.pdf) "A non-squeezing theorem for convex symplectic images
of the Hilbert ball" of Abbondandolo and Majer contains a non-squeezing result in infinite dimensions and starts with a nice discussion of its history.

Answer (score 9):

A standard way of going from a symplectic manifold to quantum mechanics is [Fedosov quantization](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214455536). Now if you want to do this in infinite dimension, that means you are interested in quantum field theory. A good place to start is [the thesis by Giovanni Collini](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09626) (a former student of Stefan Hollands) which develops such a Fedosov quantization in the QFT context.

Comment: One should note that the infinite-dimensional spaces in Collini's thesis definitely go beyond Hilbert spaces, requiring Fréchet or locally convex topologies.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: You are right, but I think you can't really do anything serious in infinite dimensional analysis/geometry with just Hilbert or Banach spaces.